# Including measurement uncertainties in pyMC3

Tags: python, regression, pymc3

I'm trying to fit some observations, which have measurement errors, to some other data with no measurement error. How do I take into account the measurement error in pyMC3? I have the following approach, which seems to give me reasonable results, but is it the right way to go about it?

```
n_samples = 20000
with pymc3.Model() as predictive_model:
    intercept = pymc3.Normal('Intercept',mu=1.0,sd=0.2)
    exponent = pymc3.Normal('A',mu=4.2,sd=0.15)
    likelihood = pymc3.Normal('Observed', 
                          mu=intercept*x_values**exponent,                              
                          observed=observed_values,
                          sd=observed_errors)

    start = pymc3.find_MAP() 
    step = pymc3.NUTS(scaling=start)
    trace_predictive = pymc3.sample(n_samples, step, start=start,njobs=4)
```

where `x_values`, `observed_values` and `observed_errors` are 1D numpy arrays of the same length.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a model `C x^A`, but you believe the data you collected looked like `C x^A + eps`.  It also looks like you *know* the measurement error exactly, somehow (this surprises me!)

If your goal is to infer something about the intercept `C`, exponent `A`, and measurement noise `eps`, I would write the model like this:

```
with pymc3.Model() as predictive_model:
    intercept = pymc3.Normal('Intercept',mu=1.0,sd=0.2)
    exponent = pymc3.Normal('A',mu=4.2,sd=0.15)
    eps = pymc3.HalfNormal('eps', 10.)
    likelihood = pymc3.Normal('Observed', 
                              mu=intercept*x_values**exponent,
                              sd=eps
                              observed=observed_values - observed_errors)

    trace_predictive = pymc3.sample(n_samples, njobs=4)
```

(note that there are better ways to initialize than the `MAP` now, and they get chosen automatically!)

Comment: "It also looks like you know the measurement error exactly, somehow (this surprises me!)"

You've misinterpreted. The OP means the measurement error is the standard deviation of each measurement. That is, SD(eps) hence also the SD(y) where y_i = y_true_i + eps